# Wp8 listpicker-display data in a text block

Tags: windows-phone-8, listpicker

I am implementing listpicker in my application;but unable to display the list picker value in the textblock.how can i accomplish it?.

Comment: If the answer solves your issue please mark it a correct. If not let us know so we can help further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use data binding for this. Its much easier.

```
<toolkit:ListPicker Name="lstPicker">
    <sys:String>Option 1</sys:String>
    <sys:String>Option 2</sys:String>
    <sys:String>Option 3</sys:String>
    <sys:String>Option 4</sys:String>
</toolkit:ListPicker>

<TextBlock Name="txtBox" 
           Text="{Binding ElementName=lstPicker, Path=SelectedItem}"
           Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextLargeStyle}" 
           VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
```

You set the `SelectedItem` of the `ListPicker` as the Value of the `TextBox`

Comment: This is working perfect. Also we should add sys namespace for using <sys:string>